# Bash - open a file on a specific instance of a program with multiple instances already open

Tags: bash, pid

I have a multitude of nifti files (medical images) that belong to different subjects. I use a program to visualize these files (*fsleyes*), but each patient has a different coordinate system and gets messy to output files from different subjects in the same instance of the viewer. So my solution is to open an instance of the viewer program for each patient, so I can open the files from each patient in their specific coordinate system.

Now, my system opens by default nifti files with fsleyes, so I can run

```
open nifti_file &
```

and view the nifti file in *fsleyes*. However, the images always open on the first instance of the program, and I need to be able to specify on which instance I want to open the file. Do you have any hints on how I can manage to do this?

In case it helps, I have a list with identifiers for each patient, and I have been able to successfully get the PID for each of the instances of *fsleyes* using the following command (each *fsleyes* instance has been opened using a command that has the patient_identifier string on it, so awk can retrieve the right PID):

```
ps  | awk '/fsleyes/{print $0}' | awk '/patient_identifier/{print $0}' | awk '{print $1}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be great to be wrong, but I don't think this is possible unless your program starts some sort of server to listen for incoming files.